# How to use antd.Form.create in typescript?

Tags: forms, typescript, antd

I have a login form created by Form.create(), but I can't pass any props to this form from parent component, compiler always notify a error like

```
error TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Compone
nt<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ childr...'.
```

### LoginForm.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'antd';
import { WrappedFormUtils } from 'antd/lib/form/Form';

interface Props {
    form: WrappedFormUtils;
    loading: boolean;
    username?: string;
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
        const { loading } = this.props;
        return (<div>form {loading ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>);
     }
}

export default Form.create()(LoginForm);
```

### LoginPage.tsx

```
import LoginForm from './components/loginForm';

const loginPage: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => {
     return (
         <div>
              <LoginForm loading={true}/>
                         ^ error here!
         </div>
     );
 };
```

My antd version is 2.11.2

---

Finally I found a solution

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component<Props & {form:     WrappedFormUtils}, State> {
  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    return (<div>form {loading ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>);
  }
}

export default Form.create<Props>()(LoginForm);
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Import the FormComponentProps

   ```
   import {FormComponentProps} from 'antd/lib/form/Form';
   ```
2. Then have your component

   ```
   interface YourProps {
       test: string;
   }        

   class YourComponent extends React.Component<YourProps & FormComponentProps> {
       constructor(props: YourProps & FormComponentProps) {
           super(props);
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then export the class using Form.create()

   ```
   export default Form.create<YourProps>()(YourComponent);
   ```

   The generic argument on Form.create casts the result to a React ComponentClass with YourProps - without FormComponentProps, because these are being injected through the Form.create wrapper component.

Comment: valid, but I needed to mandatory add:
constructor(props: YourProps & FormComponentProps) {
    super(props);
}
to actually pass a prop to a form. 
I suggest you to edit with this info.

Comment: I extend props with `FormComponentProps` this way:
```interface YourProps extends FormComponentProps {...}``` and it works for me as well.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov yeah in the new antd version they pick your props on Form.create<...> and strip FormComponentProps out

Answer (score 15):

I got a better approach from [antd](https://ant.design/components/form/) documentation

```
import { Form } from 'antd';
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form';

interface UserFormProps extends FormComponentProps {
  age: number;
  name: string;
}

class UserForm extends React.Component<UserFormProps, any> {
  // ...
}

const App = Form.create<UserFormProps>({
  // ...
})(UserForm);
```

Comment: From where do you take this?