# How to prevent antd.Form.create from swallowing Flow errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, flowtype, antd

When I wrap a component in `Form.create()`, Flow error checking stops working on props.

Component code:

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "antd";

type Props = {|
    requiredField: string,
|};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

export default Form.create()(MyComponent);
```

I invoke this component in another file:

```
<MyComponent randomField={15} />
```

with two errors: there is the addition of a nonexistent prop `randomField`, and it omits the required prop `requiredField.` I expect this error from Flow (which I get when the export is not wrapped in `Form.create()`:

> Cannot create `MyComponent` element because:
>
> - property `randomField` is missing in `Props` [1] but exists in `props` [2].
> - property `requiredField` is missing in `props` [2] but exists in `Props` [1].

But instead I get no errors.

There is an [analogous question for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898248/how-to-use-antd-form-create-in-typescript), which interestingly has the opposite problem where errors are displayed with correct usage. I tried implementing the top answer from that question, which uses `FormComponentProps`, but I still couldn't get errors to appear with my incorrect usage.